# Visual Studio 2022 pre-release nuget not used

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to use pre-release version of certain project (version 1.1.504-alpha-build-con-acc.5).

```
<PackageReference Include="ProjectX.Client" Version="[1.1.504-alpha-build-con-acc.5]" />
```

I've specified this version in project file and it seem to be installed correctly when checked in nuget manager.
When opening Interface i'm using from the project, there's a version 1.1.504.0, which have been already released by another coworker.
According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning I've tried to specify the version with [] brackets, but it didn't help.
Any ideas why VS is using different nuget version than specified?